# Can you identify this part? (Lego themselves couldn't)

Tags: part-identification

These pieces (3 shown) predate 1990. I don't know which set they belong to or what they were/can be used for. I asked Lego but they didn't know either.

[image: Lego part]

Comment: Looks like these parts belong to a system used in watches, however I couldn't find the exact part as well. Are there any numbers underside these elements?

Comment: No numbers underneath.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is most likely [Scala Jewelry Plate, Modified 2 x 2 (Human Bracelet segment)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=312c#T=C).

[image: bracelet]

Quite easy for me to find on Bricklink's search engine. All I did was type "plate 2x2 modified." Bricklink tells it appears in four sets which look like bracelet kits, but as of now it's too late to use them as bracelets because Lego has already invented [newer ones.](https://rebrickable.com/blog/262/review-dots/) You might as well use these as a bridge or something.

Comment: Wouldn't say it is "extremely easy" to find this on Bricklink as I've spent quite some time and couldn't find the piece.

Comment: (type) *plate*. (size) *2x2*. (keyword, w/o which you will not find it) *modified*. Do not include color. (result: second from last out of 25)

Comment: "You might as well use these as a bridge or something." If he had more, he might be able to use them as tank treads.

Comment: @Mazura the trouble with this piece is that it isn't listed under modified plates on Bricklink, but rather under an obscure Scala group. Which makes some sense to group parts of same functionality like Znap, Bionicle or Hero Factory do. However there is also a separate category of parts used in watches, where similar [1x2 modified piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=bb1004) is listed in this category instead. Not even in Parts catalog. Yeah, searching for "2 x 2 plate" return the result, but otherwise there's no logic unless you know the piece.

Comment: Yeah, I tried searching as well. You had more luck it seems. Thanks for figuring it out.
I a not sure about the count but I think I have like 10 of those. Rather disappointed it's from a bracelet. Was hoping for some tracked vehicle.

Comment: mindstormsboi solved it. I inherited set [312-2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=312-2#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) I recognise the tiles and the 4 by 4 and 4 by 8 clip-ons.